# InnoDB lock exhaustion with batched transactional DELETEs under DBI

Tags: mysql, perl, innodb

I am using perl and DBI to perform deletes in chunks of 1000 on a very large mysql table. But I am receiving this error: `DBD::mysql::db do failed: The total number of locks exceeds the lock table size`.

Here is the perl code with the sql statement that performs the deletes

```
my $q = q{
DELETE FROM table
WHERE date_format(date, '%Y-%m') > '2015-01' LIMIT 1000 
};

my $rc = '';
until ($rc eq '0E0') {
      $rc = $dbh->do($q);
      $dbh->commit();
}
```

In my experience this error has only occurred when trying to delete or insert a very large number of records all at once with one statement. In fact the viable solutions I have been able to find are:

1. Increase the innodb buffer pool size using the `innodb_buffer_pool_size` global variable.
2. perform the delete in chunks.

I have not tried solution 1. for two reasons. First being that it seems in my specific situation it would only increase the time before the buffer is eventually filled, though I am not sure about that, and second because we are not certain what effect it may have on the application using the database.

I would like to know:

*Why is this error occurring even though I am deleting in chunks?

*Is there a quick high level solution to this problem with perl and/or DBI?

*Any other info that could lead to a soution.

Comment: FWIW, explicitly testing that `$rc eq '0E0'` is improper -- test for truth if that's what you want, or test for zero if that's what you want.  The "zero but true" values in perl are funny, and not meant to be explicitly string matched.  For example, DBI::ping returns the equally zero and equally true value "0 but true"

Comment: How many records total, how many matching your WHERE, what is the table structure, what versions of MySQL, DBD::mysql, and DBI?  If I understand correctly, you seem to be _accumulating innodb locks_ (since you get the error periodically after batch deletes), but your `commit` [should release all innodb locks](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-transaction-model.html).  Do you get the same error if you attempt this via another, non-DBI client?

Comment: Are other people writing to the table?  Are other sessions possibly locking the table?  If you restart the failed batch delete, with no other changes to the table from any other sessions, does it succeed on the very next batch (presumably, the one on which it failed)?

Comment: I was mistaken you are correct the error was occurring at each iteration. It would take some time before throwing the error and  since I was testing the return code improperly (thanks for pointing that out) the loop would continue - so I thought it was periodic. I am very sorry for the confusion The table contains 22,473,703 records and the portion that needs to be deleted is 1,425,844. I do get the same error in my GUI client or in a shell. I think the only solution left is to move a back up to another server where we can try to increase the buffer size.

Comment: OK then I think you've got a one or two acceptable answers below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Why is this error occurring even though I am deleting in chunks?

InnoDB uses [row-level locking](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-locks-set.html):

> **14.5.8 Locks Set by Different SQL Statements in InnoDB**
>
> A locking read, an `UPDATE`, or a `DELETE` generally set record locks on *every index record that is scanned in the processing of the SQL statement.* It does not matter whether there are `WHERE` conditions in the statement that would exclude the row. InnoDB does not remember the exact `WHERE` condition, but only knows which index ranges were scanned. The locks are normally next-key locks that also block inserts into the “gap” immediately before the record.
>
> [...]
>
> `DELETE FROM ... WHERE ...` sets an exclusive next-key lock on every record the search encounters.

(emphasis added)

This means that your query will lock every row it scans, even rows that don't match the condition in your `WHERE` clause.

I don't know the exact execution details of your query, but I imagine that with a large table, it wouldn't be difficult to overrun the [default 128 MB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-locks-set.html) of `innodb_buffer_pool_size` (which I believe is shared by all sessions; other sessions could be locking rows at the same time as your query). Especially so if your query doesn't use indexes and triggers a table scan.

### Is there a quick high level solution to this problem?

The [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/delete.html) describes a simple workaround for exactly this situation:

> If you are deleting many rows from a large table, you may exceed the lock table size for an InnoDB table. To avoid this problem, or simply to minimize the time that the table remains locked, the following strategy (which does not use `DELETE` at all) might be helpful:
>
> 1. Select the rows not to be deleted into an empty table that has the same structure as the original table:
>
> ```
> INSERT INTO t_copy SELECT * FROM t WHERE ... ;
> ```
>
> 2. Use `RENAME TABLE` to atomically move the original table out of the way and rename the copy to the original name:
>
> ```
> RENAME TABLE t TO t_old, t_copy TO t;
> ```
>
> 3. Drop the original table:
>
> ```
> DROP TABLE t_old;
> ```
>
> No other sessions can access the tables involved while `RENAME TABLE` executes, so the rename operation is not subject to concurrency problems. See Section 13.1.20, “`RENAME TABLE` Syntax”.

Comment: Not obvious to me how this fits symptoms:  OP is able to batch delete for a while but _then_ hits the error, apparently regularly, suggesting lock accumulation over several DELETEs.  But the `commit` should release any locks.  In other words, given the explanation you quote, I'd expect the OP to hit this error every time or never.

Comment: @pilcrow I agree that it seems like locks are accumulating, but the OP doesn't indicate what other activity is happening on the database server at the time; there could be another regularly-scheduled activity that locks a large number of rows during some of the OP's `DELETE`s. Also, the number of rows locked by the `DELETE` itself is dependent upon what's in the table at any given time; if matching rows are sparse, MySQL may have to scan a lot of them before hitting the `LIMIT`. As the OP does successive `DELETE`s, matching rows will decrease, but the number of rows that *(continued)*

Comment: *(continued)* have to be scanned may not (or may even increase).

Comment: Good speculation; I've asked OP to clarify.

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion, I have clarified some in a comment above. also I will look further into the documentation pertaining to your answer but as of now the `INSERT INTO t_copy SELECT * FROM t WHERE ...` statement is throwing the same error

Comment: @BryanK Based on your comment about deleting 1,425,844 out of 22,473,703 records, and the following bit from the manual, I guess that makes sense. "`INSERT INTO T SELECT ... FROM S WHERE ...` sets an exclusive index record lock (without a gap lock) on each row inserted into `T`...[With the default transaction isolation level] InnoDB sets shared next-key locks on rows from `S`." This question would be a good fit for http://dba.stackexchange.com/ if you added details about your schema, showed the results of an `EXPLAIN`, etc. I'd be curious what professional DBAs think.

Answer (score 0):

1. Have `INDEX(date)`
2. `date` is of type `DATETIME` or `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP`
3. Perform the query this way:

   DELETE FROM table
       WHERE `date` > '2015-01-31'
       ORDER BY `date` DESC
       LIMIT 1000
4. stop when the DELETE has rows_affected == 0